# Corporate website design

Tags: web-development, web-services, web, websites, web-framework

We are redesigning our corporate website with the following functions:

- we want to give the marketing users flexibility and freedom to add new static pages, change the static pages or contents of static pages without the developer(s)/deployment team getting involved.
- we want developers to work on the dynamic portion of the website.

How to architect the website to make sure that the layout/look and feel of the website stays same across all the pages and achieve the above mentioned work?

Any experience? Suggestions?

Comment: I swear, strange as this sounds, having done several such projects I promise that the next one I have to do will involve just teaching the end users basic HTML and giving them a library of CSS widgets. Less work than actually building a great CMS, I feel.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1) Research the content management systems out in the world, as Mickey Sly says.

Step 2) Select one that nearly fits. Implement it as a trial. Present it as a prototype to a pilot team. Re-implement a couple of times.

Step 3) Decide if you need to implement your own CMS. I would be willing to bet a dollar that you don't.

By all means, DO NOT implement a CMS before you have experience with successful implementations. There are far too many poor implementations in the world because the developers didn't understand security, maintainability, flexibility or user experience.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it sounds like you're looking for a Content Management System or CMS. There are dozens of free ones out there on the internet that are pretty easy to setup and use. Although, it seems like you're talking about building this CMS yourself. My suggestion would be to look at some open source CMSs on Google and after you've browsed through a few you can take what you like and don't like from each and build your own.

Comment: I did look into some CMS like dotnetnuke but we will have to be dependent on what they provide. like developing against the API etc. by building our own we will have the flexibility to do whatever we want

Comment: I 100% agree with building your own. That just means it's something that the company will have forever and years down the road you wont have to fight with the vendor on getting something changed. Since your going that route I reiterate my point about looking at open sourced systems. It's definitely also a great way to start gathering requirements as well.

Comment: Who uses SharePoint for their corporate website? Are you thinking of an intranet? Marketing usually creates things for customers to see.

Comment: @JeffO Opps, sorry your right. Intranet is what I was thinking of. I'll remove that sharepoint statement.

Comment: Protip: your main website does not need to serve your apis and web services.

Comment: Thank you friends! We are exploring several CMS options and based on the certified CMS in the company, we are looking at Sitefinity as an option. Sounds like next few weeks are going to be fun. I really appreciate all the suggestions.